# No Session Hibernate in @PostConstruct

Tags: spring, hibernate, postconstruct

MyDao class have the methods to do whole persistence tasks through Hibernate SessionFactory, it works fine.

I inject MyDao in MyService as can see above, but when @PostConstruct init() method is called after injected MyDao (debugging I can see MyDao well injected) get the next Hibernate exception:

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread

My service implementation.

```
@Service("myService")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    @Autowired
    private MyDao myDao;
    private CacheList cacheList;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        this.cacheList = new CacheList();
        this.cacheList.reloadCache(this.myDao.getAllFromServer());
    }

    ...
}
```

**WAY TO SOLVE**

As *@**Yogi*** recommended above to me, I have used TransactionTemplate to get one valid/active transaction session, in this case I have implemented throught constructor and works fine for me.

```
@Service("myService")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    @Autowired
    private MyDao myDao;
    private CacheList cacheList;

    @Autowired
    public void MyServiceImpl(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {

        this.cacheList = (CacheList) new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager).execute(new TransactionCallback(){

            @Override
            public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus transactionStatus) {

                CacheList cacheList = new CacheList();
                cacheList.reloadCache(MyServiceImpl.this.myDao.getAllFromServer());

                return cacheList;
            }

        });
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Your code has a 'void' where I would not expect one: `public void MyServiceImpl`. Should this be a constructor or is this a method that you call from somewhere else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is any transaction allowed on **`@PostConstruct`** level so **`@Transactional`** won't do much here unless `mode` is set to `aspectj` in **`<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" />`**.

As per [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20160217005855/http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/50069-no-transaction-in-transactional-service-called-from-postconstruct) discussion you can use [`TransactionTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html) to start manual transaction inside `init()` to bind `session` but if you intend to strictly adhere to declarative transaction you need to use [`ApplicationListener`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener.html) to register event and user [`ContextRefreshedEvent`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/event/ContextRefreshedEvent.html) to initiate transaction.

Comment: Thank you very much, TransactionTemplate work fine for me. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running under transaction. I can see the transaction annotation but looks like you missed to activate the transaction management using annotation through the use of  using `<tx:annotation-driven/>` tag in spring context.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `MyServiceImpl.init()` is called by Spring after `MyServiceImpl` related bean construction and `@Transaction` annotation is not used to manage session lifecycle.
A solution might be consider Spring AOP around methods that use the cache instead of `@PostConstruct`