# How do I initialize database tables (insert rows into) using JPA and Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have a Spring/JPA/Hibernate application that maintains state data in a mysql table. The application is dependent on that state data being initialized properly. That is, when the application initializes, I want to ensure that a known table includes two rows-- one each with two known primary key values.

The table is "JPA managed" (sorry if that term is not correct)-- I have an `@Entity` class that maps each row in the table to an instance of that class and a corresponding DAO class that manipulates (persists, retrieves) instances of that `@Entity`.

My (unsuccessful) attempt to solve this problem used an `initialize()` method on the DAO annotated with `@PostConstruct` (as well as `@Transactional(read-only = false)`). That method instantiates two instances of the `@Entity` and has calls the `EntityManager` to persist them (I use persist instead of merge to avoid overwriting existing state and catch the `EntityExistsException` that's expected if the row(s) already exist).

I've confirmed that the `initialize()` method is being invoked and is calling the `persist(...)` method on the `EntityManager` but the database rows are not being inserted-- I've examined the mysql statement log and the expected `INSERT` statements are not present.

I can't be the first person who wants to initialize data in a JPA-managed table, right? Is there a "best-practice" for doing this sort of initialization?

Thanks!

PS: Although the table is "JPA-managed" it is not created by Hibernate. The table is assumed (by the application) to already exist.

Answer (score 0):

JPA implementations tend to delay flushing to DB until commit. Are you sure that `INSERT`s are not done even at commit time? Can you try `flush()`ing at the end of your `initialize()` method? Because of that delaying, `flush()` is needed if you want to catch some JPA exception and deal with it *inside* the same transaction that executes the DML.

**UPDATE**

As zbigniewTomczak says in his comment, `initialize()`should be transactional. The problem with that is that I am not sure that Spring is going to honor a `@Transactional` annotation in a init-method. You can try that as it is the easier option, and if it does not work, then you can try programmatic transaction management in your `initialize()` (either completely manual or using [`TransactionTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html)): Read [Spring documentation about programmatic transactions](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-programmatic)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll try this... gimme five minutes :) But shouldn't the `@Transactional(...)` annotation take care of this?

Comment: OK (again, thanks for your answer!). The plot thickens: When I add a `flush()` call to the end of the `initialize()` method I get the following interesting exception: `javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
 at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.checkTransactionNeeded(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1171)
 at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1332)` (sorry about the formatting).

Comment: With Hibernate and JTA transaction management you need active transaction to store changes to DB. I would recommend `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` instead of flushing.

Comment: Thanks to you both for your answers. I'll add the suggested `propatagation` value to the existing `@Transactional(...)` annotation and see what happens. Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi and thanks again for your help. Sadly, the simple addition of `propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` to the `@Transactional(...)` annotation didn't solve the problem. I have, however found an alternate solution that appears to work: I've implemented the `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` interface as described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346679/transactional-on-postconstruct-method). This appears to solve my problem. Again my thanks to you both for your help.