# SpringBoot with Ehcache

Tags: spring-boot, ehcache

I'm using spring boot and i have configured ehcache in my program. My Application Class looks like

SprinbootApplication.Class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "in.secondlevelcache.persistance"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "in.secondlevelcache.entity"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "in.secondlevelcache.*"})
@EnableCaching
public class SpringApplicationClass  extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

@Autowired
StudentInter studentInterfaceService;

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {

    return application.sources(SpringApplicationClass.class);
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

    SpringApplication.run(SpringApplicationClass.class, args);  
}

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean jerseyServlet(){
    ServletRegistrationBean register = new ServletRegistrationBean(new ServletContainer(),"/*");
    register.addInitParameter(ServletProperties.JAXRS_APPLICATION_CLASS, JerseyInitialize.class.getName());
    return register;
}

@Bean
public CacheManager getEhCacheManager(){
    return  new EhCacheCacheManager(getEhCacheFactory().getObject());
}


@Bean
public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean getEhCacheFactory(){
    EhCacheManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("ehcache.xml"));
    factoryBean.setShared(true);
    return factoryBean;
}

@Bean
public List<Student> getAllStudentData(){
    System.out.println("Inside the GetAllStudentData of Spring Initalize");
    return studentInterfaceService.getUser();
}
```

Ehcache.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ehcache>
<defaultCache eternal="true" maxElementsInMemory="100" overflowToDisk="false" />
<cache name="empcache" maxElementsInMemory="10" eternal="true" overflowToDisk="false" />
</ehcache>
```

My Interface Class

```
@Service
 @Cacheable("empcache")
public interface StudentInter {


public List<Student> getUser();

public List<LabelMaster> getAllLabelValue(String language);

public List<LabelMaster> getAllLocaleLabelValue();
}
```

My Entity Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Student")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@Cacheable(value = true)
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)

public class Student {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="roll")
private int rollId;

@Column(name="name")
private String name;

@Column(name="address")
private String address;

@Column(name="telephone")
private long phone;

public int getRollId() {
    return rollId;
}

public void setRollId(int rollId) {
    this.rollId = rollId;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public long getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(long phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}


}
```

I call the entity class using the repository

I call the method get user() during the server startup, i can see the query executes in my log and after that i try to call the same method by using a rest service i can see the same query fires in my log,but after that i call the same method using rest service i dint see any query

My question is 
1) I load the data from db to second level cache during my server start up, then why the query is executes while I'M calling the same method using rest service ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can remove all the ehcache setup since as of Spring Boot 1.3 it is auto-configured automatically. Since you are using the default "ehcache.xml" location, Spring Boot will auto-detect that and create the cache manager for you. If you are using a different location for the config, there is a property to teach Spring Boot where to find the configuration for the cache (`spring.cache.ehcache.config`)

Second, you can't rely on that feature in `@PostConstruct` as there is no way to ensure that all the post processing is already done (this is the same for pretty much every interceptors, [including `@Transactional` for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346679/transactional-on-postconstruct-method)).

Try to move that code to `afterSingletonInstantiated` (from the `SmartInitializingSingleton` interface). If you don't want to do that, another idea is to move that code to an event listener that is invoked when the app has fully loaded:

```
@EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
public void yourCacheStuff() {
   ///
}
```

Comment: how about invoking `yourCacheStuff()` inside `main()` after the `SpringApplication.run()`?