# Spring Boot Hibernate Postgresql @Transactional does not rollback

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, transactions

My project includes the combination of Spring Boot + Hibernate + Postgresql. Since the project started I thought adding @Transactional to the method will automatically triggered a rollback when a RunTimeException is thrown, but it seems that I was wrong. Here's the the application properties.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=sbs

# HIKARI CONNECTION POOL
spring.datasource.hikari.pool-name=SBS_Datasource
#spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=true
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=3
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=3000
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=10000
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=600000
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=select 1
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-init-sql=select 1
spring.datasource.hikari.isolate-internal-queries=true
spring.datasource.hikari.allow-pool-suspension=true
spring.datasource.hikari.register-mbeans=true
```

As you can see, the `auto-commit` has been disabled, dialect is set to `PostgreSQLDialect` and we're using hikari pool.

The situation is: this happens at start-up phase of the application. We want to load data from csv and persist into the database when the application is starting up. Here are the components:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(
        value = "sbs.api.master-data.enable-loader",
        havingValue = "true"
)
@Slf4j
public class MasterDataLoader {
   ...
    @PostConstruct
    public void loadMasterData() {
        log.info("***MasterDataLoader STARTS");
        this.loadCountryCodes();
        this.loadZipCities();
        log.info("***MasterDataLoader ENDS");
    }

    private void loadCountryCodes() {
        log.info("***Loading country codes from {}", this.countryCodeFilePath);
        try {
            List<CSVCountry> csvCountries = this.countryLoader.read(countryCodeFilePath);
            this.countryLoader.save(csvCountries);
            log.info("*** length " + csvCountries.size());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn("Exception while loading country code {}", e);
        }
    }
   ...
}
```

Code that has @Transaction inside `countryLoadder`

```
...
    @Transactional
    void save(List<CSVCountry> csvCountries) {
        dossierRepository.save(new DossierEntity());
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
}
...
```

The actual code is more complex than this but since I saw it didn't work so I decided to go with the simplest possible example.

I expected the created dossier would be removed because of @Transactional, but it wasn't.

Please help to tell what's wrong with the code or there is a problem with the technology stack (Spring + Hikari + PostgreSQL).

**SOLUTION:**

- Check this out: [@Transactional on @PostConstruct method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346679/transactional-on-postconstruct-method)

Comment: The method should be `public` yours has default accesibility. Next to that it is an internal method call which won't work. Spring uses proxies to apply AOP, that only works for method callls INTO the object, not for methods calls INSIDE the object. Finally you are calling a method from within an `@PostConstruct` annotated method, this method could execute before a transactional proxy has been created, leading to no transactions.

Comment: Why does access modifier affect the @Transactional?

Comment: Found it, thanks @M.Deinum https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346679/transactional-on-postconstruct-method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [@Transactional on @PostConstruct method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346679/transactional-on-postconstruct-method)

Comment: It is due to this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346679/transactional-on-postconstruct-method It costs me 2 hours to trace.

Comment: thanks @lugiorgi, I found it myself though :D

Comment: sorry, you were too fast ;)