# org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException in @PostConstruct

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an SpringBootApp with embedded Derby;works fine.  When I implement CommandLineRunner or @PostConstruct I get above error

> "org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException failed to lazily initialize
> a collection of role:...- could not initialize proxy - no Session".

How do I create a session with Hibernate before the app actually runs but after the applications.properties file has been loaded?  Also what is SprinBoot doing elsewhere that prevents this error in normal running?

```
 @Component
@Transactional
public class DatabaseTesting01 {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DatabaseTesting01.class);
    @Autowired
    EDITypeService ediTypeService;
    @Autowired
    VendorService vendorService;
    @Autowired
    SubscriberService subscriberService;
    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        Vendor v = vendorService.findOneByShortName("UNFI");
        logger.debug("Vendor:UNFI"+v.toString());
    }
}
```

UPDATE
This is what worked.HTH.

```
@Component
@Service("database01")
public class Database01 {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Database01.class);
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("transactionManager")
    protected PlatformTransactionManager txManager;
    @Autowired VendorService vendorService;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init(){
        TransactionTemplate tmpl = new TransactionTemplate(txManager);
        tmpl.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
            @Override
            protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
                vendorService.deleteAll();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing the `@Transactional` does over the class is applying transactional functionality (creating proxy, etc) to all public methods. So you should not rely on the initialization code such as `@PostConstruct`.
Here is the appropriate [spring reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-annotations)

> In proxy mode (which is the default), only external method calls
> coming in through the proxy are intercepted. This means that
> self-invocation (in effect, a method within the target object calling
> another method of the target object) does not lead to an actual
> transaction at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with
> @Transactional. **Also, the proxy must be fully initialized to provide
> the expected behavior, so you should not rely on this feature in your
> initialization code (that is, @PostConstruct).**

**UPD**

In your case the main problem is a loading of a one-to-many list of roles of the vendor. And it is a predictable behaviour because of the transaction absence. I hope [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346679/transactional-on-postconstruct-method) will help you to workaround a problem, but anyway just ask yourself - is it really necessary to do such a things in a `@PostCunstruct`? If not, you can just implement an alternative method in the repository, using [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) or a [jpql constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_05/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_constructor) to get rid of joined entities loading

Comment: Thank you.  However how do I configure a CommandLineRunner or @PostConstruct to properly configure for database service use?  I was using http://zetcode.com/springboot/commandlinerunner/.  Also where in SpringBoot does it configure properly?  To just better understand architeture.

Comment: Thank you, your first reference in your above clarification worked.  I updated my original for future searchers.  This is "good" what is "better" or "best"?  This is only for testing.  Should I populate the db as a separate test run or like this and just comment out the @Component?

Comment: In general you can easily remove the `@Component` because instantiation is already provided within the `@Service` implementation, however the best way is to use [integration tests](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testcontainers-integration-test) for a test purposes